# Styled Components .attrs w/ TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm a little confused on how to use the `.attrs()` function with TypeScript. Say I have the following:

**BottleBar.tsx:**

```
interface IBottleComponentProps {
  fill?: boolean
}

const BottleComponent = styled.div.attrs<IBottleComponentProps>(({fill}) => ({
  style: {
    backgroundImage: `url("./media/images/${fill ? 'Bottle-Filled.png' : 'Bottle-Empty.png'")`
  }
}))<IBottleComponentProps`
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
`;

export default function BottleBar() {

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <BottleComponent />
      <BottleComponent fill />
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

Now, the above code works, but I'm unsure why `IBottleComponentProps` is needed twice, both at the beginning and the end - And without it, I get the following:

```
Type '{ fill: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, "slot" | ... 254 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & Partial<...>, "slot" | ... 254 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & { ...; }'.
```

Additionally, with the first code example, I get a browser log as such;

```
index.js:1 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `fill`.
```

It's honestly pretty confusing, and the Styled-Components documentation isn't very clear in this regard. A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Answer 1: `Warning about fill`

**You need to choose a different name**, maybe `full`, but not `fill` for your styled component. As [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes) is a standard attribute of some HTML elements. [Also, at w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp)

#### Experiment:

If you declare `fill` to be `string` and pass it a string value, you can see a `fill` attribute added to you to `div` in **HTML DOM**, example:

```
<div
  fill="test"
  style="background-image: url(&quot;/media/images/image_file.png&quot;);" class="sc-AxiKw jDjxaQ">
</div>
```

#### `fill` is a property in SVGAttributes interface:

from `node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts`:

```
interface SVGAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
  // Attributes which also defined in HTMLAttributes
  className?: string;
  id?: string;
  ...
  // SVG Specific attributes
  accentHeight?: number | string;
  ...
  fill?: string;
  ...
}
```

That's the reason of this warning:

```
Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `fill`.
If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: fill="true" or fill={value.toString()}.
```

---

### Answer 2: `Why interface is required 2 times?`

Below is the excerpt from related interface:

```
attrs<
      U,
      NewA extends Partial<StyledComponentPropsWithRef<C> & U> & {
          [others: string]: any;
      } = {}
  >(
      attrs: Attrs<StyledComponentPropsWithRef<C> & U, NewA, T>
  ): ThemedStyledFunction<C, T, O & NewA, A | keyof NewA>;
```

`U` becomes : `IBottleComponentProps` which you pass
`C` is HTML element or react component type

And the return type is `ThemedStyledFunction<C, T, O & NewA, A | keyof NewA>`:

```
export interface ThemedStyledFunction<
    C extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.ComponentType<any>,
    T extends object,
    O extends object = {},
    A extends keyof any = never
```

where `C`, `T` were already provided. You are providing `O` by passing `IBottleComponentProps` the **2nd time**.

If you don't provide it your `BottleComponent` will look like below one with `{}` for the props i.e. no props:

[image: without]

If you provide, it will look like below one, with the right props.

[image: with]

In short, **you have to provide the interface 2 times** for now. You can provide `any` if you don't have your interface defined.

Comment: It'd be great if this was documented ANYWHERE. Thanks a lot for the solution AND the great explanation.

Comment: Just for reference, now also found in https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/28597#issuecomment-781273822

Comment: Opened a PR in https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components-website/pull/775/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like second type variable information is losing information from the first type.

Here's the definition of `attr`

```js
export interface ThemedStyledFunction<
    C extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.ComponentType<any>,
    T extends object,
    O extends object = {},
    A extends keyof any = never
> extends ThemedStyledFunctionBase<C, T, O, A> {
    // Fun thing: 'attrs' can also provide a polymorphic 'as' prop
    // My head already hurts enough so maybe later...
    attrs<
        U,
        NewA extends Partial<StyledComponentPropsWithRef<C> & U> & {
            [others: string]: any;
        } = {}
    >(
        attrs: Attrs<StyledComponentPropsWithRef<C> & U, NewA, T>
    ): ThemedStyledFunction<C, T, O & NewA, A | keyof NewA>;
```

According to that `NewA` type variable should have necessary information from `U` type.

The result is however `ThemedStyledFunction<"div", any, {}, never>`

Ideally it would be similar to `ThemedStyledFunction<"div", any, StyleProps & IBottleComponentProps, "style" | "fill">`

```js
type IBottleComponentProps = {
  fill?: boolean
}

type StyleProps = {
  style: {
    backgroundImage: string;
  }
}

const BottleComponent = styled.div.attrs<IBottleComponentProps, StyleProps & IBottleComponentProps>(({fill}) => ({
  style: {
    backgroundImage: `url("")`
  }
}))`
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
`;
```