# How to properly use TypeScript types with a Styled Component canvas on React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, canvas, gatsby, styled-components

I am creating a React component on Gatsby using TypeScript and have defined a canvas Styled Component this way:

```
const Background = styled.canvas`
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
`;
```

And to use it I am assigning types to it this way:

```
const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = Background,
  context = Background.getContext('2d');
```

But I am getting this error with the canvas type:

[image]

```
Type 'String & StyledComponentBase<"canvas", any, {}, never> & NonReactStatics<never, {}>' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLCanvasElement': height, width, getContext, toBlob, and 238 more.
```

I am also getting an error on the `.getContext()` method:

[image]

```
This expression is not callable.
Type 'never' has no call signatures.
```

I have been searching for a solution but can not find a proper one for this specific problem.
Could someone please explain to me the best way to use Styled Component canvas with TypeScript?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61980137/2873538) may be somewhat related.

Comment: Thank you @AjeetShah , I will have a look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from @101arrowz was almost right but had a problem with the context that gave me this error.

[image]

```
Object is possibly 'null'.
```

But it helped me to find a different approach with the styles being inline and solve the problem this way:

```
const Component: React.FC = () => {
  const canvasRef = React.useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  const [context, setContext] = React.useState<CanvasRenderingContext2D | null>(
    null
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (canvasRef.current) {
      const renderCtx = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');

      if (renderCtx) {
        setContext(renderCtx);
      }
    }
  }, [context]);

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas
        id="canvas"
        ref={canvasRef}
        style={{
          position: 'fixed',
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%'
        }}
      ></canvas>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Check my updated answer. I forgot to set the type of the `canvasRef` in the `useRef` generic. It should work now. Of course, your solution works, but you'll be forcing many rerenders. Just try a `console.log('hi')` in the body of the `Component` to see what I mean.

Comment: Also, the only issue with my original code was TypeScript complaining, but there should be no issue at runtime either way.

Answer (score 1):

The `Background` is a `React.Component` (i.e. a function that creates a virtual element) rather than an `HTMLCanvasElement`. Not only does the function need to be called for it to even return anything remotely like an `HTMLCanvasElement`, but you also need access to the underlying DOM element to make it work. I do have a suggestion that you might be able to try, though.

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const Background = styled.canvas`
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
`;

const ComponentUsingTheCanvas = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const context = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');
    // Do stuff with your canvas context here
  });
  return (
    <Background ref={canvasRef} />
  );
}
```

One note, I didn't type anything because TypeScript can do that automatically most of the time.

By the way, why use a styled component when you can just style inline? `styled-components` is only really useful if you [do something with the props](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props).

Comment: Hi, @101arrowz  Thank you for your answer, it made me understand some things unclear to me. I tried your code but got an error when using the context about it being null. But I liked your approach of adding the style inline. I like to use styled-components because of not only using the props but renaming my components to more meaningful names that will make the code, in the end, more legible. Your approach helped me to find a solution that solved the problem of the null on the context.